Bluetooth mouse reverse wheel scroll setting is destroyed in Windows registry each time I re-pair the mouse. How to keep the setting permanent?
How on earth do I apply "reverse wheel scroll" (to make it match "natural scroll" of the touchpad) without the setting being undone every G$% @$%n time that I re-pair the mouse to the computer?
I'm in Windows 11.
I am aware of registry options like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\{00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_Dev_VID&021532_PID&0061_REV&0001_c9d1532d297d&Col01\9&16a60742&0&0000\Device Parameters\FlipFlopWheel and setting it to 1.
I keep getting them, but the setting no longer applies when I re-pair the mouse (or pair a new mouse).
How do I keep this setting permanently and globally?

Partial answer:

export the registry key to the desktop and then double click that file to import when re-pairing the mouse. Also, the keys are set by dev_id I think, so you would export a reg key for each mouse you pair. Sub-optimal, I know.

hold on a little bit longer, because this was added in July 2024 to an insider preview build:



[Input]
[ADDED] We have updated Settings > Bluetooth & Device > Mouse to now include the option to turn off enhanced mouse pointer precision
for those that would prefer to not use it and have added a new option
for changing mouse scrolling direction.

https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2024/07/24/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-26257-canary-channel/
